# Zooming in camera make some meshes not visible

Tags: three.js, camera, render, clipping

Im using OrbitControls and when i zoom in or move camera on some angles  some of the meshes disappear.
This is my camera configuration right now :

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,0.1, 3000 );
```

I tried to decrease the near plane but it doesnt work, i also add to the meshes materials that are disappearing THREE.DoubleSide and nothing seems to work. They are also animated via new way to animate fbx.

```
object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );

mixers.push( object.mixer );

var action = object.mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
action.play();
```

dont know if that has anything relationship with the issue.

Comment: try setting `yourObject.frustumCulled = false` and see what happens.

Comment: No, there is no change on the scene.

Comment: Hmm perhaps `yourObject.traverse(o=>o.frustumCulled = false)`?

Comment: yes that's working. Thanks!